sub-menu full width on twenty twenty four wordpress theme
I have an issue with twenty twenty four theme.
I have a submenu "Shop", where so far I have a block that arrears when you click the arrow. I would like this submenu to appear full-width, under my header, but I cannot figure out how to fix that in CSS.
Here is the website URL : https://staging2.ateliermauny.fr/
website screenshot
I tried different fixes changing float, position, display:block, width:100% etc..., but it never moves

Use your browser devtools inspect facility to find out exactly where the width is being set. I'm afraid we can't help you without seeing relevant code within the question (not on an external site as the question will become useless for future readers once the problem is fixed).

The submenu has CSS code of min-width which you can override with custom CSS code. Please check the screenshot for clarification here. You can use the below code to override the CSS code
.wp-block-navigation__submenu-container{min-width: 1200px !important}

Note: You have to do it with media query differently for Desktop and Mobile device
